# How to repack an installed package in Arch linux?

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I have a snapshot (a directory that I can `chroot` into and run `pacman`) created by TimeShift that contains an earlier version a package. Now I want to revert the package of my current system to that version. How can I create a `.tar.xz` from the snapshot so I can install it?

I know I can get the file list from pacman and replace them with `rsync`. But I prefer to have a proper package so it correctly holds dependencies etc.

I noticed there was a [bacman](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=99183) which seems to be exactly what I need. But I can't find it anywhere (pacman-contrib package does not contain it anymore).

Comment: You should be able to do it manually using a `PKGBUILD`. Create an archive of the files of the package, and use it as the source, similar to any `-bin` package (e.g., https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=apex-bin)

Comment: Also, did you check `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` inside the chroot? The older package might still be there.

Comment: @Siddhartha Hi, I explicitly ignored the cache when creating snapshots to reduce the backup size, maybe now it turns out to be a bad practice.. And Yeah, I can create a tarball using the installed files. What I'm looking for is just an automated tool for this.